# Using logical operators with %in% and subset

Tags: r, dplyr, logical-operators

I have a test dataset that I have split up by quarter:

```
> test
   id quarter
1   7      Q1
2   7      Q1
3   5      Q1
4   8      Q1
5   3      Q1
6   6      Q1
7  10      Q1
8   3      Q2
9  10      Q2
10  8      Q2
11  2      Q2
12  7      Q2
13  6      Q2
14  6      Q3
15  9      Q3
16  6      Q3
17  4      Q3
18  9      Q3
19  2      Q3
20  5      Q4
21  8      Q4
22 10      Q4
23  7      Q4
24  1      Q4
25  8      Q4

subsets <-split(test, test$quarter, drop=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(subsets)) {
  assign(paste0("Q", i), as.data.frame(subsets[[i]]))
}
```

Now my objective is to find out all of the unique ids in `Q3` that are not in `Q1` or in `Q2`.  Using the `%in%` operator I try:

```
Q1_ids <- unique(Q1$id)
Q2_ids <- unique(Q2$id)

Q3_ids <- subset(unique(Q3$id), !(unique(Q3$id) %in% Q1_ids | Q2_ids))
```

but then I receive an error that `operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`.   I can subset by one vector, for example if I only use Q1_ids, but I cannot use a logical operator.  What is the solution to this using the `subset()` function or another way to approach the problem?

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(7, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 10, 3, 10, 8, 2, 7, 6, 
6, 9, 6, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 10, 7, 1, 8), quarter = c("Q1", "Q1", 
"Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", 
"Q4")), .Names = c("id", "quarter"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame", index = structure(integer(0), "`__quarter`" = integer(0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Q3_ids <- unique(setdiff(Q3$id , union(Q2$id, Q1$id)))
```

Comment: what if there are more vectors to include in `union()` ?  for example, if I wanted to union `(Q3$id, Q2$id, Q1$id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just write a function that extracts the elements you are looking for, and then call map (or an apply function) to apply the function to each of the quarters.  This particular tidyverse solution would output a named list, containing your desired output for each quarter:

```
library(tidyverse)

get_distinct <- function(x, data) {
  distinct_id <- data[data$quarter == x, 1] %>% 
      unique()
  setdiff(distinct_id, data[!data$quarter == x, 1]  %>% 
      unique())
}

quarters <- unique(test$quarter)

dat <- map(.x = quarters, .f = get_distinct, data = test) %>% 
    set_names(quarters)
```